# In python how to limit inserting a dummy to once per gvkey?

Tags: python, pandas, loops, for-loop

I have the following code which produces a one every time notch_sp goes from 11 or higher to 10 and lower, but I only want it to produce a 1 the first time it happens per gvkey.

```
df['cliff']= (df['gvkey'].eq(df['gvkey'].shift()) &
              df['notch_sp'].shift().gt(10) &
              df['notch_sp'].lt(11)).view('i1')
```

For a dataset looking like this:

```
df[['gvkey','notch_sp','am','cliff']]
Out[1]: 
            gvkey    notch_sp    am     cliff
1        1004.0        12.0    0.490      0
2        1004.0        10.0    0.490      1
3        1004.0        11.0    0.608      0
4        1004.0        10.0    0.608      1
5        329498.0      12.0      NaN      0
6        329498.0      10.0      NaN      1
7        329498.0      13.0      NaN      0
8        329498.0      10.0      NaN      1
```

So cliff needs to be one at row 2 and 6 and zero everywhere else.
I'm sorry I don't have any input on an idea to do so, but I just have no idea how to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumsum.html) compared by `1` for first group and chain by original by `&` for bitwise `AND`:

```
df['cliff']= (df['gvkey'].eq(df['gvkey'].shift()) &
              df['notch_sp'].shift().gt(10) &
              df['notch_sp'].lt(11))
df['cliff'] = (df.groupby('gvkey')['cliff'].cumsum().eq(1) & df['cliff']).view('i1')
print (df)
      gvkey  notch_sp     am  cliff
1    1004.0      12.0  0.490      0
2    1004.0      10.0  0.490      1
3    1004.0      11.0  0.608      0
4    1004.0      10.0  0.608      0
5  329498.0      12.0    NaN      0
6  329498.0      10.0    NaN      1
7  329498.0      13.0    NaN      0
8  329498.0      10.0    NaN      0
```